# Simplify nested if/else conditionals (JS)

Tags: javascript

**I want to simplify this nested if/else conditionals or statements**, but I don't know-how because I want them easier to read and more practical. *I'm just a freshman at programming. That's why I get stuck with this spaghetti code.*

```
setmessage = 'You have requested that the file type of the site screenshot be:'

normalized = message.content.toLowerCase();
npng, npdf = normalized.substring(0, 3);
nhtml = normalized.substring(0, 4);

if (npng == 'png') {
   message.channel.send(setmessage + '**PNG**');
   areyousure();
} else if (npdf == 'pdf') {
   message.channel.send(setmessage + '**PDF**');
   areyousure();
} else if (nhtml == 'html') {
   message.channel.send(setmessage + '**HTML**');
   areyousure();
} else {
   message.channel.send(invalidmessage);
   getouttahere();
}
```

Comment: This actually doesn’t look so bad.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't, but I'm gonna add more, and it would make the code longer.

Comment: `npng, npdf = normalized.substring(0, 3);` looks bad. ;)

Comment: @TheCodingWolfito No that line does not do what you think it does. `console.log('npng', npng);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an array of the possible substrings the message starts with, and use `.find` to see the substring that matches. If there is one, call `.send` with it - otherwise, pass in `invalidmessage`.

```
const permittedExtensions = ['png', 'pdf', 'html'];
const normalized = message.content.toLowerCase();
const ext = permittedExtensions.find(ext => normalized.startsWith(ext));
if (ext) {
  message.channel.send(setmessage + '**' + ext.toUpperCase() + '**');
  areyousure();
} else {
   message.channel.send(invalidmessage);
   getouttahere();
}
```

Comment: why not includes?

Comment: The length of the substrings changes, so you'd need a regex or something to extract the match from the start of the string to use `.includes`. I think `startsWith` and `find` would be a bit less ugly

Answer (score 0):

Using a reg expression you can match the start of the string.

```js
function test(message) {

  var extension = message.content.match(/^(pdf|jpg|html)/);
  if (extension) {
    console.log(extension[1].toUpperCase());
   // message.channel.send(setmessage + '**' + extension[1].toUpperCase() + '**');
    // areyousure();
  } else {
     console.log('invalid');
     // message.channel.send(invalidmessage);
     // getouttahere();
  }
}


test({ content : "pdf" });
test({ content : "jpg" });
test({ content : "html" });
test({ content : "sh" });
```